# 'Series' object is not callable using pd.crosstab

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to use pd.crosstab on python with series but does not seem to work. shows that 'Series' object is not callable

`pd.crosstab(byoccupation.UserID, byoccupation.Gender)`

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[866], line 1
----> 1 pd.crosstab(byoccupation.UserID, byoccupation.Gender)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py:682, in crosstab(index, columns, values, rownames, colnames, aggfunc, margins, margins_name, dropna, normalize)
    676 from pandas import DataFrame
    678 data = {
    679     **dict(zip(unique_rownames, index)),
    680     **dict(zip(unique_colnames, columns)),
    681 }
--> 682 df = DataFrame(data, index=common_idx)
    684 if values is None:
    685     df["__dummy__"] = 0

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

not sure what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably doing a wrong importing of Pandas or overwritten the class `pandas.DataFrame`. With the snippet you provided is not possible to find the solution, but as an example the following code should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list("ABCD"))

pd.crosstab(df.A, df.B)
```